# Create custom User Control for Acumatica

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls, acumatica

I am attempting to create a custom User Control that is usable in the Acumatica Framework. Documentation is very limited so I was hoping someone may have some experience/examples of how best to implement?

It appears possible by creating a `WebControl` derived from `PXWebControl` and creating a global *JS* function with a matching name.

Comment: I can provide you an example of how to work with a pure HTML/JS control and have it interact with the graph, but as far creating an ASP.NET control that will seamlessly work with the Acumatica framework, it's not something I've seen before. I tried it a while ago but wasn't able to figure out how to have my global JS functions loaded - didn't try very hard however. Will be watching this question with great interest!

Comment: This question is too broad; [questions asking only for generic examples are off-topic for Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291259/2747593). Instead, start writing code, and come back when you have a more specific problem. Be sure to show us [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

To create a custom User Control in an easy way, you need to:

- *Open* Customization of your project **(System - Customization - Customization Project)**
- On the left side, you can see your screens in your customization. Find screen that needs or add needed screen. *Go to the necessary view.*
- Select *add controls* and add your needed control.

You can see in an image provided below.

[image]

Comment: The product doesn't really support custom control (no option for that in Add Control tab). On the other hand JavaScript is correctly highlighted as the closest you can get to a custom control..

Comment: @HuguesBeauséjour technically any custom asp.net control can be used with Acumatica Framework. The other question is that the Layout Editor won't automatically show or manage that control with drag&drop. But the question is not specific to Layout Editor.

Comment: Correct, this is a possibility when creating new pages.

Comment: I'm not sure you can customize existing pages with any asp.net control. The customization parser will likely break on unknown controls.